# Admob not showing ads and is reporting not being active

Tags: admob, google-ads-api

I am just now getting this message but on my dashboard, everything is active and in my code, I have the correct adunits with a banner ad. I have downloads and they are growing but now I am seeing that ads are not showing up. How do I get this corrected outside of contacting the help desk?

I validated my code with the correct id's.

Comment: check what error code you're getting in logcat ?

Comment: Hi @AbhishekAryan, I debugged the code and I am in unity, it doesn't give a response, but, I checked the  dashboard of AdMob and it had activity.